# Separating two header files with the same name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

In my project we use the standard `#include <math.h>` functionality. On top of that we also have a `#include "Math.h"` file. However now when we reorganized our projects and included all the header files in "Additional Include Directories". This have made that Visual Studio 2010 no longer can separate them. What can I do to separate them in a nice way. For now i have solved it by just renaming my Math.h to _Math.h but this is not a nice solution i think.

Comment: to be honest, it is not nice way to name own class with name of existing one...

Comment: How about placing them in a subdirectory?  `#include <project/math.h>`?

Comment: How would you distinguish two unrelated functions with the same name? Probably in meaningful namespaces. How might you replicate that sort of functionality at the code organisation level? Maybe separating into directories, and using the directory name in the `#include` path? Maybe filename prefixes? Also, as this is tagged `C++`, have you considered that you should probably be `#include`-ing `<cmath>`?

Comment: BoBTFish whoah, you already said it all. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you facing a naming conflict, can you be confident it's not a result of functionality duplicate? If you're sure your math.h is somehow special, that's a good reason to highlight distinctive feature in it's name or path.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by other comments:

1) If possible, avoid using standard/frequent names for your source/header files

2) If you cant, consider placing your files in (sub)directories

```
#include <myproject/Math.h>
```